# Undefined reference to function, compiling with makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I'm currently working on an assignment and am trying to compile it using a makefile, which currently looks like this:

```
all: myshell

myshell: main.o LineParser.o
    gcc -g -m32 -Wall -o main.o LineParser.o myshell

main.o: main.c
    gcc -g -m32 -Wall main.c -o main.o

LineParser.o: LineParser.c
    gcc -g -m32 -Wall LineParser.c -o LineParser.o

.PHONY: clean

clean: 
    rm -f *.c myshell
```

LineParser contains both a .c file and a .h file, and I've included the .h file in my main.c so it should compile properly. However, I cannot compile since I'm getting an "undefined reference to 'parseCmdLines' and 'freeCmdLines' (functions that are in LineParser). Besides those two functions, everything compiles properly with the current makefile, so I believe that the problem lies in the makefile, but I don't know exactly what I need to change.

**Main.c**

```
#include "LineParser.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void execute(cmdLine *pCmdLine){
    int i = execv(pCmdLine->arguments[0],pCmdLine->arguments);
    if (i == -1)
        perror("Error: ");
}


int main (int argc , char* argv[], char* envp[])
{
    char cwd[MAX_ARGUMENTS];
    char userInput[2048];
    struct cmdLine * command;
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL)
        perror("getcwd() error");
    else
        printf("Current Working Directory is: %s\n", cwd);
    printf("Write a command:\n");
    if( fgets (userInput, 2048, stdin)!=NULL ) {
        command = parseCmdLines(userInput);
        freeCmdLines(command);
   }
}
```

Comment: Typo: the name of the object to build follows `-o`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `-c` option to have GCC do compilation only (create object file, no linking to build an executable) and `-o` option to specify the output file, not one of the input files.

```
all: myshell

myshell: main.o LineParser.o
    # put -o at proper place
    gcc -g -m32 -Wall main.o LineParser.o -o myshell

main.o: main.c
    # add -c
    gcc -c -g -m32 -Wall main.c -o main.o

LineParser.o: LineParser.c
    # add -c
    gcc -c -g -m32 -Wall LineParser.c -o LineParser.o

.PHONY: clean

clean: 
    rm -f *.c myshell
```

Comment: Thanks! That ended up doing the trick! For some reason I read not to add the -c flag, but it makes sense to compile the LineParser before.